# How to make condition by styles?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, express

I have my `scss` styles for desktop and mobile version:

```
.categories {
  width: 250px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-right: 40px;
  min-width: 250px;

  @media only screen and (max-width: 965px) {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 20px;
  }
```

Is there any opportunity to create such `mounted` method in `vue` file which will be check if user uses mobile or desktop version?

As and example on pseudocode:

```
async mounted() {
   if (@media) {
    // do something
 }
}
```

Comment: For which purpose would you need this ?

Comment: I have a filter with categories that is on the mobile and on the desktop version and I need to make sure that these filters are not shown on the mobile version by default (until the user clicks on the button) There is a lot of code there, so I can't show it. I could just add `if` condition, but it won't work, because if it defaults to false, it won't be shown on desktop version at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

media queries in css works based on the window size. you can get the same window size with javascript also

```
window.innerWidth
window.innerHeight
```

and use these variables in if condition will do your work.

If you want your view to be dynamically change on window resize then,you have to create a custom event on window resize to remount the component whenever the window resizes

```
window.resize = <your event handler>
```

Comment: Yeah, that is what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`window.resize` can create performance issues, so I recommend using `window.MatchMedia()` instead. `window.resize` fires every time the window is resized - at every pixel - so not just when the resizing is "finished".

With the `window.MatchMedia()` method, you define a breakpoint (or an array of breakpoints). Then you add an event listener that only fires when you actually reach a breakpoint.

In your case, it could look something like this:

```html
const mediaQuery = '(max-width: 965px)';
const mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia(mediaQuery);

mediaQueryList.addEventListener('change', event => {
    console.log(window.innerWidth);
  if (event.matches) {
    console.log('The window is now 965px or under');
  } else {
    console.log('The window is now over 965px');
  }
});
```

You can read more in depth about it here: https://webdevetc.com/blog/matchmedia-events-for-window-resizes/)